# Help me with the CSS of IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-9

I am having a problem with my website, [www.diaplasisgym.com](http://www.diaplasisgym.com/). The problem is the sub menu. It is working fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but if you open it with IE the slide bar is hiding the submenu. How i can fix this?

Here the code of the menu and submenu:

```
  #mainMenu {  
    position:absolute;   
    bottom:-80px;   
    left:0px;  
    background:url(images/menu.png) no-repeat;   
    width: 961px;   
    height:98px;   
} 

#mainMenu ul li {     
    float:right;     
    height:70px; 
}

#mainMenu ul li a {     
    font-weight:bold;    
    display:block;     
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:25px 20px 0;     
    font-size:15px;
}

#mainMenu ul li a span {     
    font-size:10px;         
    color:#999;

}

#mainMenu ul li a:hover {   
    text-decoration:none;    
    color:#2fc8ff;
}

#mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul{ 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style-type: none; 
}

/*Top level list items*/
#mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li { 
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left; 
}

/*Top level menu link items style*/

* html #mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack to get sub menu links to
    behave correctly*/ display:
        inline-block; 
}


/*1st sub level menu*/
#mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul{
    position: absolute; l
        eft: 0; 
    display: none; /*collapse all sub menus to begin with*/ visibility: hidden;
    width:auto;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    background:
        url(images/secondarydropdown.png)
        repeat-y; box-shadow: 3px 6px 7px 1px
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    border-radius:8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px; 
    border: 1px solid #232323; 
    border-top:none; /*border-bottom:1px solid #222;*/ 
}

/*Sub level menu list items (undo
style from Top level List Items)*/
#mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{ 
    float: none; 
    display: list-item;
    padding:0; 
    height:3%; 
}


/* Sub level menu links style */
#mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a, #mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a:hover{ 
    text-align:left;
    /*background:#000;*/
    line-height:20%;
    font-size:13px; 
    padding: 22px 5px 15px 28px; 
    color: #ffffff;  
    font-family:
        Century Gothic, Arial, sans-serif; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.3);  
    background: url(images/secondary-dropdown-bullet.png)
        no-repeat 15px 20px; z-index:9999; 
}

#mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a:hover {     
    color:#1FA2E1;     
}

#mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a.last, #mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu ul li
ul li a.last:hover {     
    border:none; 
}

/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html #mainMenu.ddsmoothmenu{
    height: 1%;
} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/
```

Comment: still a bit dirty..how about showing us in jsfiddle.net? :) welcome to SO btw

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for IE 7
paste this in your stylesheet

```
/* IE 7 Fix */

#header{z-index:1001 !important;}
#content{z-index:100 !important;}
```